# iOS AVPlayer Does Not Play the Next Song in a Playlist After App is Backgrounded Then Screen is Locked

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, playlist

I am working on this iOS app that plays music from URLs. Currently it has no issues playing through a playlist while the app is foregrounded, backgrounded, or even when the screen is locked ONLY IF the app was in the foreground prior to locking.

If the app is backgrounded THEN has the screen locked, the next song will load, but it will not play.

My question is: **How can I get the AVPlayer to play the next song in a list while the app is in the background and the screen is locked?**

Below is the code I am using to load and play the songs...

```
- (void)loadNextSong {
    if (self.playlistIndex < self.playlist.count-1) { //check to see if the next track is in bounds of the playlist array
        self.playlistIndex++;
        [self.player pause];
        [self serviceDidFetchSong:self.playlist[self.playlistIndex]];
        [self.player play];

    } else { //play the first song if we reach the end of the playlist
        self.playlistIndex = 0;
        [self.player pause];
        [self serviceDidFetchSong:self.playlist[self.playlistIndex]];
        [self.player play];
        }
    }

- (void)serviceDidFetchSong:(Song *)song {
    if (song.audioFileURL != nil) {

        if (![self.song.audioFileURL isEqual:song.audioFileURL]) {
            if (self.timeIntervalObserver) {
                [self.player removeTimeObserver:self.timeIntervalObserver];
            }

            AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:song.audioFileURL options:0];
            AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:asset];

            self.player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

            //this is just for a visual of the song progress
            __block __weak SongPlayerViewController *blockSelf = self;
            self.timeIntervalObserver = [self.player addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds((1.0f/5.0f), NSEC_PER_SEC)
                                                                                  queue:NULL
                                                                             usingBlock:^(CMTime time){
                                                                                 [blockSelf updateProgressBar];
                                                                             }];
        }

        self.song = song;
    }
}
```

After trying to debug with some console logs and break points, I have verified that [self.player play] is definitely being called and that the correct URL is loaded each time.

My info.plist file has audio and fetch enabled for the required background modes.

The next song just doesn't seem to play at all when the app has been backgrounded and the screen is locked.

Any insight or suggestions would be much appreciated. Thank you.

**EDIT**
This seems to be an intermittent issue which appears much less frequently since the release of iOS 9.3 which leads me to believe this may have been related to the OS...?

Comment: can you share a sample project?

Comment: this is just a small piece of a much larger app and this piece of code wasn't really based on another project (at least not intentionally) so i don't have a sample project to share... is there anything else i could provide to help point to a solution?

Comment: I am experiencing something very very similar. Only occured when I updated to iOS 9.3 and Xcode 7.3. When a song ends, and app is in background with screen locked,  the next song is loaded and `player.play()` is called, but the `player.rate` remains at 0. Extremely frustrating I wonder if this is something to do with iOS 9.3. I have even opened up a background task to make sure the app doesn't fall into suspension, still no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works when you play it twice.

player?.play()

player?.play()